# Is there any Java CSS formatter util?

Tags: java, css, code-formatting, formatter

I need to format (not compress) CSS code, so that  unreadable CSS code is formatted to be readable. I need this as Java library.

Comment: Found [this javascript](http://jsbeautifier.org/) online utility. It probably shouldn't be too hard to replicate in Java.

Comment: @arunkumar has a good point. There are many online formatters that could be probably be invoked from a Java app. Alternatively, if they are Javascript based then you could format via Rhino which comes bundled with Java since version 1.6 - http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/scripting/.

Comment: @Paul , actually I was thinking along the lines of `code.replaceAll("([};])", "$1\n");` along with some kind of simple stack maybe to keep track of  function body and opening and closing curly brackets, loops etc. and tab the current line by how deep the current stack depth is. But yes Rhino is probably the easier solution.

Answer (score 2):

I just tried using the beautifier from http://jsbeautifier.org/ in Rhino.

I downloaded the JS from:

https://github.com/einars/js-beautify/blob/master/beautify.js

Then started Rhino (must be in Rhino installation directory):

`java -jar js.jar -opt -1`

Load `beautify.js` (assuming you copied it to the Rhino installation folder, else use different file path):

`load("beautify.js")`

And then beautify `beautify.js` itself!

`js_beautify(readFile("beautify.js"))`

This can also be embedded into your Java app. Give [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961406/generate-well-formatted-javascript#1961807) a try.

Comment: The last link you gave is broken